# Intent/action from notification not passed on when user clicks on notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I'm developing an app that displays notifications when there's an incoming event. When the user clicks on the notifications, they will be brought to an activity with a specific fragments within the app. On a Samsung Galaxy Note 2 with Android 4.1.2, this works. However, on a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3, the activity does not receive the correct action, but rather receives the intent "android.intent.action.MAIN".

Also, the S3 doesn't seem to get the extras that I'm putting in the intent either. The Note 2 receives them fine.

The notification code is as follows:

```
Intent launchIntent;
String myType, myAction;
// myType and myAction are programmatically set
launchIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
launchIntent.putExtra("Type", myType);
launchIntent.setAction(myAction);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, -1, launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
  context).setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
  setContentText(notificationMessage)
  setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
  setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
  setAutoCancel(true)
  setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
  setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
notificationManager.notify(notifyId, noti.build());
```

Does anyone know why it works with 1 device and not another? Are there any changes in intent from 4.1 to 4.3?

Thanks.

Comment: You set `launchIntent.setAction(myAction);` but your `myAction=null`. What is myAction value? and why are you setting this manually?

Comment: myAction is set programatically, I'm using it to pass information to the intent. I've verified right before calling PendingIntent.getActivity() that the action is not null, but rather the set value.

Comment: Also, the S3 doesn't seem to get the extras that I'm putting in the intent either. The Note 2 receives them fine.

Comment: It's very difficult to solve device specific issue.

Comment: it looks like the S3 is getting a standard launch Intent, not the one you built. That's why the action is wrong and the extras are missing.

Comment: How can I get the S3 to get the intent that I built? Shouldn't this be standard across Android devices? I would expect intents to be something very commonly used in apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, turns out I need to set my intent flags to `"Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP"` for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

There are problems on some devices when the `requestCode` in the `PendingIntent` is not > 0. There are even some devices where the `requestCode` needs to be > 1000.

Change this:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, -1, launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to this:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1001, launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Tried this, and even tried a value of 10000, but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Please explain how you know that it isnt working. Please post your manifest.

Comment: I know it isn't working because in MainActivity's onResume() when I getIntent() and get the action, the intent is "android.intent.action.MAIN" and the action is null.

Comment: `getIntent()` will return the `Intent` that the activity was started with. If the activity was originally started by launching it from the list of applications, then `getIntent()` will return this launch `Intent`. Is your `MainActivity` declared with a non-standard `launchMode`? is `onNewIntent()` being called in `MainActivity`?